# How to perform a smoothing operation on a wavelet decomposition in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, smoothing, wavelet, decomposition

I have been asked to perform thresholding and smoothing on the wavelet coefficients in the wavelet domain to improve de-noising of an image. I am able to do thresholding by using the Matlab function **wthcoef2**, but I don't see a function for smoothing that is consistent with Matlab's representation of the wavelet coefficients.

Below is the code I have right now:

```
F = imread('lena_std.tif');             % Reads the image
F_gray = rgb2gray(F);                   % Converts from RGB to Gray scale

gausQ = input('Add White Gaussian Noise?: ','s');

if gausQ == 'Y'
    F_noisy = imnoise(F_reshape,'gaussian');
    F_wavelet = F_noisy;
else
    F_wavelet = F_gray;
end

%% 
% Asks user for the wavelet decomposition level and the type of wavelet to 
% use.
J = input('Choose the wavelet decomposition level: ');
wavelet = input('Choose the wavelet name: ','s');

[C,S] = wavedec2(F_wavelet,J,wavelet);  % Multi-level wavelet decomposition

%%% Thresholding done by C = wthcoef2(C,S,N,T,SORH); %%%
```

My main issue is that the wavelet coefficients are held in a vector, C, that is 1 row by however many columns, and this representation doesn't allow for smoothing operators to be applied (at least not in the way I understand).

I considered trying to reshape the wavelet coefficient vector, but I didn't know how to incorporate the bookkeeping matrix, S, into it correctly.

If anyone has any insight on this issue, please respond accordingly. If I need to add anymore detail to this question, please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: by bookkeeping matrix, do you mean the HAAR DWT / DFT?

Comment: oh, nevermind. http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec2.html

Comment: I've been looking through Matlab's libraries & I don't see any way to isolate the coefficients on all levels and integrate them back into the decomposition matrix. I guess a function has to be written to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at any of OpenCV's solutios? might give you ideas. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got the idea of lowpass-filtering in the wavelet domain. It is definitely novel but it may not be what you want.

Maybe the more direct two-dimensional fast wavelet transform gives you a better idea of which coefficients go to/come from which image positions:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ug/two-dimensional-discrete-wavelet-analysis.html